# Is Derris-Kharlan's tree in Tales of Symphonia it's original one, or it's new one?

Tags: tales-of-phantasia, tales-of-symphonia

in *Tales of Phantasia*, Dhaos came from Derris-Kharlan seeking a Mana Seed from Aselia's Great Tree due to a Mana Canon having been developed and used in Derris-Kharlan depleting it's mana and causing it's tree to die. At the end i recall that Cress and his party found out about Dhaos true motive and decided that when it was ready, they would give Derris-Kharlan a Seed from their tree.

in *Tales of Symphonia* Cruxis is based on Derris-Kharlan which was believed to have enough mana on it to revive Sylvarant/Tethe'alla's Great Tree (i don't know the name of their combined world) and in a couple of Skits in *Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World* Tenebrae points out that the Great Kharlan Tree (Sylvarant/Tethe'alla's original one) is a cut from Derris-Kharlan's and that Mana wasn't naturally apart of the world and thus why Ratatosk was need to regulate it's balance

I am wondering if the Tree mentioned on Derris-Kharlan is it's original tree, or the second one that would come from after the events of *Tales of Phantasia*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tree mentioned in *Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World* by Tenebrae is the original one as *Tales of Symphonia* is set before the events of *Tales of Phantasia*

> Aselia (アセリア Aseria?) is the name of the world in which Tales of Phantasia takes place. ... as well as the combined world of Sylvarant and Tethe'alla from prequels Tales of Symphonia and Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World.

Source: [Aselia](https://aselia.fandom.com/wiki/Aselia)

according to the wiki linked, the Elves of Derris-Kharlan came to Aselia and transplanted the Kharlan Tree from Derris-Kharlan bringing life the the planet while, the elves took a cutting from the Kharlan Tree to replant it on Derris-Kharlan (as opposed to taking a cutting and planting it on Aselia)

it is this cutting that would have died between the gap of *Tales of Symphonia: Dawn of the New World* and *Tales of Phantasia* and thus the tree that Dhaos was looking to get a seed from is the new tree that was born after the events of *Tales of Symphonia*.

this is backed up that in *Tales of Phantasia* Martel is Guarding the Tree

[image: Martel at the start of the game]

[image: Martel in the anime with Mint]

and Martel was only born as a Guardian Spirit of the tree after it was reborn in *Tales of Symphonia*